# Urn with white and black balls, probability of n white with nth position

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white and $b$ black balls. $n$ extractions with replacement are made. What are the probabilty of:

1. get $r$ white, $P(W=r)$
2. get $r$ white with white ball on n-th, n-th and n-th extraction (example third, sixth and ninth)

The first is easy:
$P(W=r)=\dbinom{n}{r}(\frac{w}{w+b})^r(\frac{b}{w+b})^{n-r}$

For the second question I need to use the conditional probability, right?

---

Edit with solution:

$P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$, where $P(E)=(\frac{w}{w+b})^3$ and $P(F)=\dbinom{n-3}{r-3}(\frac{w}{w+b})^{r-3}(\frac{b}{w+b})^{(n-3)-(r-3)}$

Comment: The second problem can be solved using basically the same method as the first problem.

Comment: The draws are independent, no need for conditional probabilities.  You have the three specified events and then you need to draw $r-3$ white balls in $n-3$ draws.

Comment: what do you mean by saying : "on n-th, n-th and n-th extraction" ? If you simply mean the probability to get a particular arrangement of $r$ white balls and $n-r$ black bals the answer is $(\frac{w}{w+b})^{r}(\frac{b}{w+b})^{n-r}$.

Comment: The answer you gave has been deleted. I inform you that the solution you provided there is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the event up in two independent events:

- $E$: On the third, sixth and ninth extraction a white ball shows up.
- $F$: On $r-3$ of the other $n-3$ extractions a white ball shows up.

To be found is $P(E\cap F)$ and since the events are independent we have: $P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$.

So to be found are $P(E)$ and $P(F)$.